# Getting value from MSB of 16 bit register

Tags: java, bit-shift, cpu-registers, bit

I have 16 bits register which contain some values in **LSB** and **MSB**:

**LSB:**
At bit 0...1 the value is 0
At bit 2 the values is 0

**MBS:**
At MSB I need to write value 20

So the value that should be written in register is 0 + 0 + 20 = 160

When I'm reading register the I'm doing it on this way:

for the 1st value in bit [0...1]:

```
firstVal = (valFromReg & (((1 << 2)-1) << 1) / 2)  
secondVal = (valFromReg & 4) / 4
```

But how to read/convert the third value to get number 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a `short` is a (signed) 16-bit value. You want to split that into 3 values:

- Value `a` is a 2-bit value in bits 0-1
- Value `b` is a 1-bit value in bit 2
- Value `c` is a 13-bit value in bits 3-15

Bit-wise, that can be represented like this: `cccc cccc cccc cbaa`

To extract the 3 values from the 16-bit `reg` value, you'd do this:

```
short reg = /*register value*/;
int a = reg & 0x0003;
int b = (reg >> 2) & 0x0001;
int c = (reg >> 3) & 0x1fff;
```

To go the other way, you'd do this:

```
short reg = (short)((c << 3) | (b << 2) | a);
```

This of course assumes that the values are within value range, i.e. a = 0-3, b = 0-1, and c = 0-8191.

Answer (score 0):

Some things in the question are not quite clear for me...
like:

> ***At MSB I need to write value 20***

back in my times MSB was only 1 bit and was only possible to write true or false...

anyways...

A 16 bits signal fits pretty good in an integer...
so you could basically get that register and manipulate it as an integer, then representing that as a binary number **AS STRING** will lets you to get the **MSB** or even the bit at any wanted position...

Do this:

## Example

```
int register = -128;
String foo = String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(register)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(register);
System.out.println(foo);
System.out.println(foo.charAt(0));  //char at 0 is the MSB....
```

Comment: Maybe I explaind my problem little bit wrong. As I explaind in my first post the first 3 bits are reserved for some values. From bit [0...1] the max value is 3, bit 2 value can be 0 or 1, and the third value can be bettween 0 and 255. My problem is how to store that third value and read back from register?